# XML SimpleXMLElement returns nodes, DOMXPath returns error

Tags: php, xml, dom

In this web page, I have a php script to recreate divs on the page based on XML data.  The script is called directly from the HTML page inside `<body> </body>`.

```
<body>
 <div id="page" class="demo">
 </div>

 <?php
   // script for recreating divs calls SimpleXMLElement or DOMXPath
 ?>
</body>
```

When I get the XML nodes with SimpleXMLElement, there are no errors, the nodes are returned.  When instead I try DOMXPath, there are errors.

This returns the nodes.

```
$nodes = new SimpleXMLElement('communities.xml', null, true);

foreach($nodes as $node) // loop through 
{
  //restore divs from node information      
}
```

This doesn't return the nodes and gives errors.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load('communities.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query('COMMUNITY');

foreach($nodes as $node) // loop through 
{
  //restore divs from node information      
}
```

To extend the script to get more information from the nodes I thought of using xpath. The additional information I want to show is: NAME: text to show for each url contained in the div (Google.com), URLC: url corresponding to the text (http://google.com).  The XML file has nodes like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 
<COMMUNITIES>
  <COMMUNITY ID="c000010">
    <NAME>New000010</NAME> 
    <TOP>50</TOP> 
    <LEFT>50</LEFT> 
    <WIDTH>150</WIDTH> 
    <HEIGHT>150</HEIGHT> 
    <URLS>
      <URL ID="u000038">
        <NAME>Google.com</NAME> 
        <URLC>http://google.com</URLC> 
      </URL>
    </URLS>
  </COMMUNITY>
</COMMUNITIES>
```

The strange problem is that elsewhere, in ajax calls from javascript functions I get information from the XML file with xpath without any problems.  Why doesn't the DOMXPath method work in that situation?

**EDITS * NEW INFORMATION**

Here is the php file called through ajax from the html page.  This is where SimpleXMLElement works.  But if I try to create a new `DOMdocument()` then call xpath.  The new DOM document isn't created.

```
<?php

function get_nodes() {
// load SimpleXML
/* $nodes = new SimpleXMLElement('communities.xml', null, true); */

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load('communities.xml');

// get document element  

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query("//COMMUNITY");

foreach($nodes as $node) // loop through 
{

        echo "<div id = '".$node['ID']."' class= 'comdiv ui-widget-content' style = 'top: ".$node->TOP."; left: ".$node->LEFT."; width: ".$node->WIDTH."; 

height: ".$node->HEIGHT.";'> \n";            echo "   <p class = 'comhdr editableText ui-widget-header'>".$node->NAME."</p>\n";

        echo "   <a href='#' onClick=\"delete_div('".$node['ID']."');\">Delete</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;\n";
        echo "   <a href='#' onClick=\"add_url('".$node['ID']."');\">Add URL</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;\n";

        echo "</div> \n";

        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
        echo "  $('#".$node['ID']."').resizable();\n";
        echo "  $('#".$node['ID']."').draggable();\n";
        echo "  $('#".$node['ID']."').draggable('option', 'handle', '.comhdr');\n";
        echo "</script>\n";

}
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n";
        echo "  $('.comhdr').editableText();\n";
        echo "</script>\n";

   return;
}

echo get_nodes();

?>
```

Comment: Strangely enough there is no error now but DOMXPath doesn't seem to find the nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had folder permission issues.  The folder containing the XML did not have permission set for the script to write the updated XML.

Answer (score 0):

Community is not the root of the xml.  Try `$nodes = $xpath->query('//COMMUNITY');`

This should select any COMMUNITY nodes in your xml document.  If you only want to select them when they're children of the root element, then try:

`$nodes = $xpath->query('/COMMUNITIES/COMMUNITY');`

Comment: Tried this `$dom = new DOMDocument(); $dom->load('communities.xml'); $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom); $nodes = $xpath->query('/COMMUNITIES/COMMUNITY');` This doesn't return the nodes. SimpleXMLElement does with this: `$nodes = new SimpleXMLElement('communities.xml', null, true);`

Comment: When I was able to get node information with xpath this was through an ajax call to php from a javascript function.  Does that explain why xpath doesn't return the nodes when called directly from the HTML page?